# Imperial units, math and geometry nodes

Tags: geometry, mathematics, units

I have been trying to follow a YouTube tutorial about geo-nodes. ([Luminous labs - BUILDINGS With BEGINNER GEOMETRY NODES 3.0 - Part 1 Color Blocks](https://youtu.be/zC1FvVv5xmA)).  I have tried it with my units set to metric and it works fine but if I try it with my units set to inches, the top level doesn't work.  I have narrowed it down to the multiply/add math node.  The top level start location is way too high.  If I divide by 25.4 its closer but still not correct.  It there a work around to translate between metric and standard the I have not found?  Blender 3.0

Comment: There is some discussion at https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes-units/25833, it's not yet solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also having this issue I think it is using the output of the math node as a Blender unit which I believe is 1m. Then when it inputs into the mesh it converts it to inches. 1m is 39.3701 inches so if you divide the number by 39.3701 it should be right. I'm guessing it is a bug unless there is a place to set the units for the geometry nodes.

Comment: thanks, this workaround is effective